# MSI WIX: Does patch install requires admin rights?

Tags: wix, patch, wix3.5, windows-installer

Trying to make patch.msp for my MSI and try to install this patch. But it is asking for admin rights.
1) During my actual MSI installation it does not ask for admin rights.
2) But during Patch installation/update it is asking for admin rights.

Is there any way we can install/update the patch without admin rights?

Below is my Patch.wxs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
 xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'>

 <Patch
    AllowRemoval="yes"
    Classification="Update"
    Comments="Patch for FooTesting Software V 1.0.0"
    Description="Update for Foo Testing Software V 1.0.0"
    DisplayName="Foo Testing Patch"
    Manufacturer="Foo Inc."
    TargetProductName="Foo testig">

    <Media Id="1000" Cabinet="FooTesting.cab">
        <PatchBaseline  Id="FooTesting" />
    </Media>

    <PatchFamily
        Id="MyPatchFamily"
        Version="1.0.1"
        ProductCode="44139BED-5F1A-4C1E-BE12-C7148BE11189"
        Supersede="yes"/>

</Patch>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do this, here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372388(v=vs.85).aspx

but if the product has already shipped and you didn't sign it then it's too late and the answer is no. Your original MSI install didn't elevate at install time? That's curious but without details it's hard to comment as to why that happened, and why your patch does.

Answer (score 0):

As PhilDW has pointed to, this could be done for example with **User Account control patching** (UAC patches, formerly known as "LUA patches").

Whereas MS officially doesn't support this for installs on server OS, it works with a little tweak (reg entry). Unclean, but sometimes you need those things.

Additionally one idea:
It is never too late for delivering a special very small patch which (though needing admin rights for it's own) could enable **other** (future) patches which are signed correctly, to install without admin rights, even if your product setup has already shipped.
(That special patch could be delivered by domain admin(s)/tools then to make it's use convenient.)
Done that. Worked great.

This is not unclean at all. To the contrary: Same special patch is necessary, if the lifetime of your delivered software is several years or decades: In other words, if your company's certificate is going to expire, what happens normally every 1-3 years.

Because:
An expired certificate works still for older delivered patches, but would stop you from building new patches signed with that certificate. So you need a new certificate, unknown to your old delivered product, .., and that's why you will need a special "certificate-enabling" patch for this situation too. Done that..

But the real-world security gain of certificates is somewhat overestimated knowing all what is known in 2015.. But it's one of the few things we are capable of, so..

There is a second official method by Microsoft called "**Elevated patching**". It's use is quite seldom and by reading the official doc it is restricted to per-user applications. Basically with this you can say: A patch which is lying on this special drive and path has to be "secure" by definition. Not so secure like certificates, but..you have read my comment.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I will not comment this more, because:
All mentioned methods can be only recommended for MSI experts or if you have one around as a consultant.

Third:
Common way companies go, if they have no MSI expert knowledge or have need to install full MSIs also without elevated rights or just much money to spend is to write full install/update services or handle those things by their admins and their scripts.

Security note again- concerning this third approach:
Of course from a user standpoint, every update service which is running all the time and has to have elevated rights, reduces security. But when I look to which updates, if automatic or not I am forced to install every week for every internet connected machine (starting with updates by Microsoft, by antivirus software, which is known to be the best hacker door at all, and by companies starting with an "A"), a small update service by a "smaller" company has realistically not a strong effect on security.